# UWP navigation from child page frame to main page frame

Tags: xaml, navigation, uwp, frame

I am developing an UWP app, I am getting an issue with back root frame navigation, I have main page in that I have frame, I navigate all pages into this frame ,, dashboard.xaml, orders.xaml....etc,    I my orders.xaml I have another frame...in that frame I navigate 3 forms(xaml pages with a cancel button) when I hit cancel buton in any of those pages, I need to navigate to my orders page back...  So I am facing problem with getting main page frame to navigate my Orders.xaml into that,,please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should rethink your design. Three levels of navigation is too complex for user friendlyness. Try swapping out usercontrols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want. For example, you can define a public static property in `Mainpage` that exposes the `Frame`.

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static Frame MainPageFrame;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //Frame1 is the name of the Frame in XAML
        MainPageFrame = Frame1;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then in the order details page, use this property to navigate.

```cs
MainPage.MainPageFrame?.Navigate(typeof(Orders));
```

Or you can take advantage of [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper) and get the parent `Frame` i.e "Frame1" like:

```cs
//this.Frame gets the Frame holds the order details page (i.e "Frame2") 
FindParent<Frame>(this.Frame)?.Navigate(typeof(Orders));
```

The `FindParent` method here is a help method uses [`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_VisualTreeHelper_GetParent_Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyObject_) method like the following:

```cs
public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parentObject == null) return null;

    var parent = parentObject as T;
    return parent ?? FindParent<T>(parentObject);
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much Jay...Its working Using VIsualTreeHelper method

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(orders));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try the above, I navigate my orders page into the wrong frame (not the main page frame). Mainpage-->Frame 1--> Orders.xaml-->createOrder(button)--> click--> xaml page with 4tabs and a Frame2 -->for each tab I navigate a page(form) to take the order details from user, each form have cancel,click on cancel I should navigate to orders page(I.e into the Mainpage.xaml Frame1)